# Do atoms exist in hybrid form in nature, or do they form hybrid orbitals during molecule formation?

Tags: hybridization

Do atoms exist in hybrid form in nature, or do they form hybrid orbitals during molecule formation?

Take methane for example. Does carbon atom exist with $\ce{sp^3}$ hybrid orbitals in nature and then hydrogen forms bond with only $\ce{sp^3}$ carbon atoms?
Or does carbon form $\ce{sp^3}$ hybrid orbitals during the formation of $\ce{CH4}$?